# Make ColdFusion accept ASP.NET credentials

Tags: c#, asp.net, coldfusion

How can I tell a ColdFusion server that my user is authenticated as XXXX credential? Currently they need to sign in from one server to the next. My primary web server is C#/ASP.NET and the older web server is ColdFusion.  I would like once they use forms authentication to the primary server that ColdFusion recognize those credentials.

Comment: How does the user navigate from the ASP.NET server to the ColdFusion server?  By clicking a link in the browser, or do some of the ASP.NET pages do a server-side redirect to the ColdFusion server?

Comment: Also, do the ASP.Net and ColdFusion servers share the same domain name?

Comment: Yes, they are on the same Active Directory domain and yes, they will click a link in the browser.  I can do redirect if need be but am trying to migrate as much away from Coldfusion as possible.  This is really a stopgap while that happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the user remains on the same domain like "mydomain.com", you can create a cookie and store its value in DB with user reference id.
when the user hits your coldfusion servers , read the cookie , validate it in your db and get the user information back.

don't forget to assign cookie domain as below:

```
cookie.Domain=".mydomain.com";
```

so other servers in different subdomains can read your cookie.

if the user does not remain on the same domain or if your web applications do not use the same domain , I can suggest you to use something like [OAuth](http://oauth.net) or implement one of your authentication system similar like FaceBook does.